# Jenkins external credentials storage on CyberArk

Tags: jenkins-plugins, credentials, cyber-ark

How to use external CyberArk vault to store credentials in free version Jenkins?
[Here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin) you can find info regarding the standard jenkins credentials plugin - that provides an API for external storage.
But after digging a while on the net, I’ve found that:
1.  [Cyberark vault is available on Cloudbees Jenkins only](https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/admin-cje/securing/)
2.  [HarshiCorp vault plugin is available for free](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HashiCorp+Vault+Plugin)
3.  [Here](https://simonuvarov.com/hacking-jenkins/) is a nice example how wrong permissions policy can lead to exposing all credentials. I tried it, works like a magic! :)

Answer (score 1):

You really don't want to store credentials (or any sensitive secret, really) in Jenkins. It's not a vault and should never be used as one. Otherwise you'll end up with your Jenkins servers becoming a major target for attackers.

Instead, integrate your Jenkins pipelines to pull secrets securely into executors only when needed, and discarded when the build/test job is done. This is easily done with something like [Summon](https://cyberark.github.io/summon/), which is integrated with many vaults already, including [Conjur](https://conjur.org) (which is a CyberArk product, too). Both are open source offerings.

[This blog post](https://www.conjur.org/blog/2018/01/26/secure-task-runner.html) describes an approach to integrating Jenkins with a vault along the lines of what I've described above.

Comment: Thanks. But we still have many freestyle jobs with plugins that use credentials plugin as a creds provider. I’m looking for a solution for those jobs

Answer (score 1):

Appears that CyberArk released Jenkins plugin which supports that scenario:
https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/AAM-DAP/Latest/en/Content/Integrations/jenkins.htm

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at https://github.com/tmobile/t-vault .
This will eliminate the need to manage policies. You could create one safe per project folder or job in jenkins.

You can create approles and grant access to safe for the approle. Each project can use corresponding approle. You can grant access to individuals to the safe as well. Users can then use the webui to author and update the secrets.